Which is More Valuable in Computer Science: Conference or Journal Publications?
In the field of computer science, there seems to be a unique emphasis on where research findings are published, with significant weight often placed on conference papers compared to other fields where journal publications may hold more prestige. I'm curious about the current perspectives and experiences of academics in computer science regarding this distinction.
Why might a publication in a top-tier conference be viewed as more prestigious or valuable than a journal publication in computer science?

As far as prestige goes, either at the same "tier" would be valuable in a CV.
The advantage of conference publications, however, is at least twofold. First, the time to publication is shorter than for journals since the conference is held on a date certain. The implication is that the community learns of advances much earlier.
But more important, IMO, is that you actually go there to meet people and have a chance to develop a circle of collaborators and, since many (most?) conferences in CS are annual affairs you can keep the contacts current over time. It is a good way to build a reputation, as it was for me. Think of a conference as a social event as well as a professional one. You meet a lot of people if you work at it. And an implication, again, is that the community gets a chance to discuss results with authors in person and relatively soon.
So, the CS community has decided, at least implicitly, that the "value" of those face to face meetings is important (very) beyond the value of an entry in a CV.
